# Use a scala companion object for spring controller instead of implementing at the service layer?

Tags: java, spring, scala, design-patterns

I'm using a scala spring controller. In my experience java spring controllers are lightweight classes which call some service method and perhaps do some logic before returning a value/collection to the presentation layer(jsp).

A scala companion object seems a nice fit for the service layer. So instead of the controller calling methods within the service layer use a companion class ? The reason for a companion class is to provide helper methods to main class, so using a companion controller makes sense.

Is this a good pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think should use a scala trait which contains the contract for the service method and add an implementation class for trait methods. Similar to abstract factory pattern.

This question is related to [Why use a service layer instead of a helper class for spring controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028568/why-use-a-service-layer-instead-of-a-helper-class-for-spring-controllers)